# Usage of dry and dried

Tags: past-tense, british-english

What is the difference among these questions:

A . Have clothes dried?

B. Have clothes gotten dry ?

C . Have clothes gotten dried?

Comment: You posted the same question also on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356897/usage-of-dry-and-dried